# Openjdk Java in Ubuntu 12.04 missing

Tags: installation

I'm install OpenJDK Java on my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

But I keep having java not found:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

What's the reason here? I tried reinstall, even deleting /usr/lib/jvm but it still doesn't work.

There is no java in /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin, only javac and other things. Also when I run javac, this is the error:

```
javadoc: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The last line, `Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>`, doesn't say nothing?

Comment: I thought I should have java after installing openjdk-7-jdk? They are the other packages?

Comment: I installed java perfectly on my laptop (with a clean ubuntu installation). I guess my desktop has some missing things, so there's a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1):

To install OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

The `openjdk-7-jre package` contains just the Java Runtime Environment. If you want to develop Java programs then install the `openjdk-7-jdk` package afterwards. Then you can do

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```